# Embed MS Word in asp3 Web Page

Tags: asp-classic, ms-word

Does someone knows how can i Embed MS Word in asp3 page?

TY

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need some sort of client-side plugin to do that.  You might be able to find a third-party library that could render it as Flash (or Silverlight, etc), but you won't be able to do this with ASP Classic alone.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed it as an iframe, which would require the client machines to set their file types to "open in browser", registry script [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927009).
This will only work in IE though.